# Capturing command output in a shell variable isn't working

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting, and  need to output a  series of commands to a local variable in a shell script, but keep on failing. For instance, the output of `grep -c` to a variable that will be use in an `if` statement. If anyone can redirect me over to a source that explains the process, I will appreciate.

```
#!/bash/sh

myVar = ls ~/bin | grep -c $0
```

Comment: You can use `backticks`:
myVar = \`ls ~/bin | grep -c $0\`

Comment: Indeed, flagged as duplicate.

Comment: @Bartez: It's [better to use modern command-substitution syntax `$(...)` instead of legacy syntax `\`...\``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082); also note that your command still has spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: @mklement0, one of the beautiful things about the editable dupe-list support is that we can close a question with *multiple* duplicates, if it's simply a composite of errors for which we already have questions with answers available. And frankly, if a question has more than one underlying problem, I'd argue that that's an argument in favor of eligibility for close-as-overbroad more than it is a saving grace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Makes sense - didn't even know that specifying multiple duplicates is an option.

Comment: That's a fairly new change -- as long as you have a dupehammer in one of the relevant tags, see the "edit" button next to "This question already has an answer here:", which will take you to an interface where you can modify the dupe list.

Answer (score 4):

Posting your code at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) gives you valuable pointers quickly:

```
myVar = ls ~/bin | grep -c $0
^-- SC2037: To assign the output of a command, use var=$(cmd) .
      ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
                           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

If we implement these pointers:

```
myVar=$(ls ~/bin | grep -c "$0")
```

Also note that your shebang line has an incorrect path - the `#!` must be followed by the full path to the executing shell's binary.

**Resources** for learning `bash`, the most widely used POSIX-compatible shell:

- Introduction: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html
- Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide
- Cheat sheet: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet